# Как сделать, что бы glob.glob() искала изображения разных форматов?

Tags: python

В директории есть файлы изображений вперемешку с другими файлами. Имена файлов изображений являются числами (напр. `234.jpg`, `3456.jpeg`, `111111.png`, `4.bmp`).

Файлы с расширением `jpg` я получаю так:

```
image_files = glob.glob(''.join([dir, '/', '[0-9]*.jpg']))
```

Как расширить данный код, что бы получить файлы с расширениями `png, jpeg, bmp, jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отфильтровать нужные файлы, используя `str.endswith()` (не тестировано):

```
import os

for entry in os.scandir(dir):
    if (entry.stem.isdecimal()
        and entry.name.endswith(('.png', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.jpg'))):
        print(entry.path)
```

Альтернативно, можно регулярное выражение использовать:

```
import os
import re

found_image = re.compile(r'\d+\.(?:jpeg|jpg|bmp|png)').fullmatch
for entry in os.scandir(dir):
   if found_image(entry.name):
       print(entry.path)
```