# Открыть файл, если известно только расширение

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, файловая-система

В директорию поступает файл, название которого постоянно изменяется с расширением .jpeg, как его можно открыть, после чего удалить используя python?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Выбор последнего по дате файла из каталога](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477013/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как сделать, что бы glob.glob() искала изображения разных форматов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765338/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Алгоритм:

- С помощью `glob` можно найти файлы по указанному шаблону. Например, `glob.glob('C:/images/*.jpeg')`
- С помощью `open` открыть и считать содержимое.
- С помощью `os.remove` удалить.

Код:

```
import glob
import os

filename_list = glob.glob('*.jpeg')
print(filename_list)

for filename in filename_list:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        img_data = f.read()
        print('{} bytes'.format(len(img_data)))

    os.remove(filename)
```

Консоль:

```
['screenshot.jpeg']
128574 bytes
```

---

Если нужен только один файл, тогда:

```
filename = filename_list[0]  # Первый файл
# или:
filename = filename_list[-1]  # Последний файл

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    img_data = f.read()
    print('{} bytes'.format(len(img_data)))

os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: имя text в заблуждение вводит при чтении файла с картинкой. `jpeg_data` ближе к истине.